# How to keep xmlhttp connection open after receiving stray response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an application which sends POST data to a php script which processes the data and then sends a response back.

I've been having a problem which nobody can figure out where the script receives blank GET data from somewhere which sends a blank response to the AJAX while the script is processing the POST data.

The problem is that after receiving this response it will no longer receive the response from the original POST data sent to the script. I need to somehow keep the connection open to receive the response from the POST data regardless of the stray GET response.

(Please note that many have tried to solve the source of the mysterious GET request to no avail, so I need a workaround for the problem):

Here's the AJAX:

```
function SendPHP(str, callback){

str = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str);


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php", 
    data: str,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success: function(msg) {
          alert (msg);
        callback(msg);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.toString());
        if (err.status == 200) {
                callback(err);
        }
        else { alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status); }
    }
});


}
```

How can I ensure this receives the response from the POST data sent after it receives a blank GET response?

Comment: Have you viewed the execution in a tool like firebug to see exactly what is being passed to and from the server?  Based on the above, I would say something else is being executed somewhere else within the script.  Viewing the network traffic should greatly assist with trying to find the root cause.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried testing using Chrome Restful client to rule out my javascript being the culprit. Turns out the GET request still gets thrown in even when using restful client. Trust me, I've tried everything to find out what it is... and other people have looked into it and nobody can figure it out.

I just need to figure out a workaround and just accept the problem right now.

Comment: Is it possible that we could have a look at the PHP code from sendmail.php which is where the culprit seems to live? There are a lot of folks here who might be able to ID the GET request.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that the response to a totally different, second request is received and handled by the code that made the first request …? That sounds _highly unlikely_, because request and response getting “disassociated” would be a major bug in the underlaying browser internals itself. Any chance we could see this “live” to have a look at this ourselves?

Comment: I replicated the problem by stripping away everything but the bare necessities to get the same error in the php, see my previous question here which has the php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080155/what-could-be-sending-get-requests-to-my-php-script

Comment: Note I've asked several questions related to this on here and on different forums and nobody has been able to crack it to date, so I have accepted that I just need a workaround. Basically I just somehow need to get the POST response after getting the GET response. The restful client is able to do this, it receives both responses, but my AJAX only gets the first one to come back (the GET response).